# Katrograph (Python) - Inconsistent Conditional Styling?

Tags: python, css, svg, kartograph, choropleth

I am currently attempting to generate a choropleth of median home values by county with [Kartograph.py](http://kartograph.org/docs/kartograph.py/).  I was able to previously build a choropleth by way of a configuration and CSS string contained within my [Notebook](http://ipython.org/notebook.html). (Note that `tel` is my variable of interest, and `dbf_in` is a [pandas DataFrame](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/dsintro.html#dataframe) containing the information in the .dbf table associated with my state shapefile.)

```
#Create color map
col_map=dict(zip(dbf_in['tel'],dbf_in['color']))

#Generate configuration dict
config={"proj":{
            "id":"laea-usa"},
        "layers":{
            "USA": {
                "src": shp_dir+"cb_2013_us_state_5m.shp",
                "attributes":"all"},
            "Lakes":{
                "src": shp_dir+"ne_10m_lakes.shp",
                "subtract-from": "USA",
                "filter":{
                    "scalerank":0}}},
        "bounds":{
            "mode":"bbox",
            "data":[-180,15,-65,55],}}

#Initialize Kartograph obj1ct
K=Kartograph()

#Generate style sheet
css_list=[]
for i in range(1,5):
    css_list.append('#USA[tel='+str(i)+']{fill: '+col_map[i]+'; stroke: #FFFFFF;}')

css='\n'.join(css_list)

#Generate blank map
K.generate(config, outfile='TEL_bind_states.svg',stylesheet=css)
```

Just for completeness, here is the CSS string:

```
#USA[tel=1]{fill: #fcbba1; stroke: #FFFFFF;}
#USA[tel=2]{fill: #fb694a; stroke: #FFFFFF;}
#USA[tel=3]{fill: #ca181d; stroke: #FFFFFF;}
#USA[tel=4]{fill: #67000d; stroke: #FFFFFF;}
```

In a nutshell, I was able to dynamically build my CSS string, and it yielded an SVG version of the following image:

[image: choropleth by state]

A similar protocol was followed to create a state level choropleth:

```
#Map colors to counties
col_map=dict(zip(acs['id5'],acs['color']))

#Generate style sheet
css_list=[]
for key in col_map.keys():
    css_list.append('#County[geoid='+key+']{fill: '+col_map[key]+'; stroke: #FFFFFF;}')

css='\n'.join(css_list[1:])

#Generate configuration dict
config={"proj":{
            "id":"laea-usa"},
        "layers":{
            "County": {
                "src": shp_dir+"tl_2014_us_county.shp",
                "attributes":"all",
                "simplify":3}},
        "bounds":{
            "mode":"bbox",
            "data":[-180,15,-65,55],}}

#Initialize Kartograph obj1ct
K=Kartograph()

#Generate blank map
K.generate(config, outfile='blank_US_cty.svg',stylesheet=css)
```

Here is the first section of the CSS string:

```
#County[geoid=16079]{fill: #fee0d2; stroke: #FFFFFF;}
#County[geoid=33017]{fill: #fdc5ae; stroke: #FFFFFF;}
#County[geoid=16073]{fill: #fee1d4; stroke: #FFFFFF;}
#County[geoid=16071]{fill: #fee3d7; stroke: #FFFFFF;}
#County[geoid=16077]{fill: #fee1d3; stroke: #FFFFFF;}
#County[geoid=16075]{fill: #fee1d3; stroke: #FFFFFF;}
#County[geoid=48093]{fill: #feeae0; stroke: #FFFFFF;}
#County[geoid=06115]{fill: #fdd0bc; stroke: #FFFFFF;}
#County[geoid=06111]{fill: #fa6648; stroke: #FFFFFF;}
```

This time, however, I can't seem to get the colors to bind to polygons like I could with the states.  This time, it yields the following image:

[image: Blank County Map]

Any thoughts on why this is happening?  I did consider that maybe a dictionary with over 3000 items was problematic, but I got the same results when I tried to color by a variable with only five unique values.

Comment: Are you sure that `geoid` is the correct attribute name for counties?  Also, you might try removing the `simplify` parameter from the configuration.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. Yes, `geoid` is correct.  I actually had to inspect the shapefile to capture the right format for the IDs, which I got from the `geoid` field.  I started without the `simplify` factor, and I ended up adding it to make things move faster.  In the end, it made no difference.